# YOLO dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python Error

Tags: python, macos

Recently I began working on a YOLO object detection. Here is my code so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load Yolo
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
print(classes)
```

But for some reason, it gives me this error 
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/archieshou/PycharmProjects/YOLO/venv/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
I'm on macOS does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This exact code causes the error? Without even loading an image, just loading the network?

Comment: @LouisLac Yea I cut it down to just printing classes and it gives me that error